# Interpolate discrete points to create a 3D surface and highlight points

Tags: plotting, image3d

I have some discrete points in 3D:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/syl7w3s30tc30b9/amycoo.xlsx?dl=0

I have the following problem:

1. I want to create a 3D surface from those points and need to somehow interpolate the "outer" points.
2. I want to make this shape/surface a bit transparent and highlight some points on or in the interior of it, e.g. an arrow pointing at that point with a text label showing a value.

To make this more clear: Let's say the points describe a brain area and I want to create a continuous version of the shape of this area, but also highlight specific points which represent the result of some data analysis, i.e. select the first point which has a value of 10.

ListPointPlot3D was a first start, but then I get stuck and hope for some guidance.

Thanks!

Comment: Is something like `ConvexHullMesh` what you're looking for w.r.t. #1?

Comment: Maybe look into `ListSurfacePlot3D[]` as well...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a simple example:

```
(*This is just me getting your data into an array of triples since I copy-pasted it.*)

data = ToExpression /@ 
   Partition[StringSplit[a, WhitespaceCharacter], 3];

(*now data looks like {{x,y,z},{x,y,z},...}*)
```

You can use Show with `ConvexHullMesh` and `Graphics3D` for annotation, and `HighlightMesh` to change the style. I just plotted a point at the centroid and put an arrow pointing to that spot as an example:

```
hull = ConvexHullMesh@data;
Show[
 HighlightMesh[hull, Style[2, Opacity[0.5]]],
 Graphics3D[{
   Red, 
   Point[RegionCentroid@hull], 
   Arrow[{# + {5, 5, 5}, #}] &@(RegionCentroid@hull)
   }]
 ]
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

Comment: Wow! Thanks, thats exactly what I wanted! Two follow-up  questions though: 1. How can I add a text at the beginning of the arrow? 2. Can I somehow get a list of the points that only lie on the outer surface?

Comment: `MeshCoordinates@hull` will give you the coordinates of the vertices, and you can use `Graphics3D[{Text["label",{x,y,z}],Arrow[...]...}]`. That will be fairly basic, if you want something nicer, I'd suggest searching the site for info about annotating `Graphics3D` I'm pretty certain that's been discussed before.

Comment: Great, thanks again!